# How to include an existing XML file in a created DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, dom

I create a new XML File with DOMDocument in PHP. That works fine. In between the document I want to add an already created XML File. How can I do this?

Existing XML Document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <books>
  <book>
  <magazine id="0" time="2014-02-18T14:42:06.0Z" type="0">New magazine</magazine>
  </book>
</books>
```

With the DOM functions of PHP I create another XML file. This works fine. Now I load the file above and create a fragement with:

```
$fragement = $document->createDocumentFragment();
$fragement->appendXML($this->xmlparser);
```

But now I dont know how to add the fragment to my document. I tried:

```
$document->documentElement->appendChild($fragement);
```

This has no effect on my XML Document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `appendXML()` with that document as it would add another XML declaration, which is only allowed at the start of a document. In general `appendXML()` is a bad idea anyway as you're playing fast and loose with raw XML data. Use a second DOM, import the document node into the first and append it.

---

#### Like so:

```
$xml1 = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root><notbooks/></root>
XML;

$xml2 = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
<book>
    <magazine id="0" time="2014-02-18T14:42:06.0Z" type="0">New magazine</magazine>
</book>
</books>
XML;

$dom1 = new DOMDocument();
$dom1->formatOutput       = true;  // These formatting options are only used
$dom1->preserveWhiteSpace = false; // for demonstration purposes here.
$dom1->loadXML($xml1);

$dom2 = new DOMDocument();
$dom2->loadXML($xml2);

$node = $dom1->importNode($dom2->documentElement, true);
$dom1->documentElement->appendChild($node);

$dom1->loadXML($dom1->saveXML()); // Just to make it pretty for the output below.

echo $dom1->saveXML();
```

---

#### Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <notbooks/>
  <books>
    <book>
      <magazine id="0" time="2014-02-18T14:42:06.0Z" type="0">New magazine</magazine>
    </book>
  </books>
</root>
```